# Finding optimal time series using convolution

Tags: classification, time-series, data-mining, convolution, anomaly-detection

we logged sensor data while milling a workpiece. At several points, the workpiece was damaged and this induced a certain sensor data time series. Due to noise and since its a real world measurement, this certain sensor data time series is somewhat different for each workpiece damage that occurs. In my dataframe, i have the sensor data and the points where a damage occured.

I want to detect workpiece damages using convolution on the sensor data. My challenge now is: how to identify a certain time series which gives me the best performance when convoluting on the sensor data.

I thought about using historic data with workpiece damages and finding the optimal time series (maybe using simulated annealing) which gives me the highest value when summing up the convolution.

Maybe there is a smarter way to do this or somebody can tell me whether there is an algorithm to do this.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: What does it mean identify the best performing time series? You want to find the work piece that has the fewest damages?

Comment: Are you looking to identify the timestamps where there was damage on the workpiece?

Comment: What kind of sensor data do you have? Dimensionality and measurement type(s).